# PHP include path for subclasses

Tags: php, oop

I'm having an issue with the include/require path. Since the code style is OOP, the problem comes when subclassing, since the path is relative to the first includer file. For example:

```
// path: /class/entity/A.class.php
class A { /*definition*/ }


// path: /class/widget/B.class.php
require_once("../model/entity/A.class.php");
class B extends A { /*definition*/ }


// path /ajax/some_request.php
require_once("../class/widget/B.class.php");
//.. some code to execute
```

The problem is that since the require path is relative to `some_request.php`, it won't find `A.class.php` because the path would end up being `/model/entity/A.class.php` where it should be `/class/model/entity/A.class.php`

Answer (score 2):

You can use relative paths to do this (which you already have in there):

If you want to go up two directories you would do:

`require_once("../../path/to/my/file.php");`

From your structure it looks like you would want something like:

`require_once("../../../classes/model/entity/A.cass.php");`

Am I missing something from your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$path = dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/my/path";
```

to deference from the parent directory of the current file. To use your code as an example...

```
// path: /class/model/entity/A.class.php
class A { /*definition*/ }

// path: /class/widget/B.class.php
require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/model/entity/A.class.php");
class B extends A { /*definition*/ }


// path /ajax/some_request.php
require_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))."/class/widget/B.class.php");
//.. some code to execute
```